# Given a recording SID, how can I download the recording file to local drive (using Twilio node helper library)?

Tags: node.js, twilio, helper

I am using the Twilio Node Helper Library to make a call and record it.

According to the [API link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-get), GET should return a WAV file, but in my case it just returns a json with the recording metadata.

This is what I'm writing:

```
twilioClient = require('twilio')(config.twilio.acct_sid, config.twilio.auth_token)
var request = twilioClient.recordings('RE01234567890123456789012345678901')
                           get(function (err, recording){ // <- this "recording" is JSON
```

It doesn't matter if I tack on a '.mp3' to the end of the SID, I always get a JSON.

Ideally I want to write something like this:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('/Users/yasemin/Desktop/rec.mp3');
twilioClient.recordings('RE01234567890123456789012345678901')
    .get(function (err, recording) {
      if(!err){ recording.pipe(file); }});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this and had to develop my own code to handle this.

Here is the code I came up with below

```
con.on('getvmx', function(data){

    comModel.find({_id: data.id}, function(err, results){
      var https = require('https');
      var options = {
        host: 'api.twilio.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + sid + '/Recordings/'+ results[0].sid  + '.mp3',
        method: 'GET',
        auth: sid + ":" + auth,
        agent: false
      };
      var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('binary');
        var mp3data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
           mp3data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
          try{
              var fileName = "/var/www/tcc/public/vm/" + results[0].sid + '.mp3';
              fs.writeFile(fileName, mp3data, 'binary', function(err){
                if(err){
                  return console.log(err);
                }else{
                  console.log("File Saved");
                  con.emit('vmload', results);
                }
              });
            }catch(err){
            console.log(err.message);
          }
        });

      });
      req.end();
      console.log(results);

      //load all messages
      //load line from reach message
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Node Helper Library doesn't have recoded file downloading capability at the moment.**

This is the response from Twilio Support:

> Looking at the documentation on our web portal, you are certainly
>   correct, downloading the .wav or .mp3 is possible via API call.
>   However, from what I can see looking at the Node example code here:
>
> https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/recording
>
> And the documentation from the Twilio-Node developer here:
>
> http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/#recordings
>
> It looks to me like the helper library doesn't actually support direct
>   downloading, just viewing the recording data. You can download the
>   application through an HTTP call, as shown in the original docs link
>   you noted on your Stackoverflow question. Let me know if you need help
>   with that.
>
> In the mean time, I've reached out to the author of the library to see
>   if this is by design or a feature to be added to the library. It's
>   open source of course, so you could make a pull and add it yourself if
>   you like!